# ¿Porque me sale que es nulo al hacer set a la variable desde un jframe?

Tags: java, poo, jframe, nullpointerexception, jtextfield

Mi problema es que intento hacer un set a una variable día desde un jframe pero me marca que es nulo

Metodo para hacer el set al a variable día en una clase llamada fecha
String day2;

```
   public void setdia(String dia){
    day2=dia;

         }
```

Método del buton con el cual hago el set al presionarlo,la variable dia.gettext es el textfield del cual quiero que se haga set del texto que se ingrese

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    motor.nuevaFecha.setdia(dia.getText());


}
```

Lo que me crea conflicto es que si intento hacer set a la variable día desde la clase Main si lo hace, y lo compruebo utilizando el metodo get pero por mas que le muevo a mi código no logro que funcione haciendo el set desde el codigo del jframe
Tengo una clase llamada motor que esta ligada a los jframes y a la clase de los sets y gets.

Comment: `String dia` y `JTextField dia` no son lo mismo, te sugiero por eso renombrar tu variable` String dia` para que observes más claramente el error.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: Si al momento de dar click en el botón no hay nada en el `JTextField` hay `NullPointerException`, comprueba que estas recibiendo los datos de `dia.getText()`, es posible que estés haciendo referencia al compo equivocado, comprueba el nombre de variable del `JTextField`. Ahí podría estar el problema.

Comment: El problema no es hacer set a la variable `day2` con tu función `setdia`. Esa función tal cual está no puede darte `null` como tú dices en ningún caso porque lo que hace es guardar lo que recibe como parámetro, bien sea un `String` o un `String` con valor `null`. El problema lo tienes cuando en el `actionPerformed` del botón intentas acceder al objeto `dia` que debe ser un `JTextField` y ejecutarle el método `getText()`. Ese objeto `día`, en ese punto es `null`, así que `null.getText() ===== > NullPointerException`